# Getting Travis to skip pushing a tag if it exists

Tags: git, bash, push

have only recently started using Travis CI for build testing. Have come a long way in just a few days and having great fun with it.

Have builds passing successfully but now running my tests under multiple php environments results in only the first test passing on pushing the tag / build number to the repo and subsequent tests failing with

`! [rejected]        v2.2017.22 -> v2.2017.22 (already exists)`

My bash code where it does the push is as follows:

`before_deploy:
- git config --global user.email "${GIT_EMAIL}"
- git config --global user.name "${GIT_NAME}"
- export GIT_TAG=v1.0.$TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER
- git tag $GIT_TAG -a -m "Tag Generated from TravisCI for build $TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER"
- git push https://${GH_TOKEN}@github.com/${TRAVIS_REPO_SLUG} --tags`

What I would like to do (as simple as possible) is the following, excuse the very lame wording of what I want to achieve here :) hope someone can help me with a very simple line of bash to achieve this.

`before_deploy:
- git config --global user.email "${GIT_EMAIL}"
- git config --global user.name "${GIT_NAME}"
- export GIT_TAG=v1.0.$TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER
- git tag $GIT_TAG -a -m "Tag Generated from TravisCI for build $TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER"
- git fetch --tags
- #if tag $TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER already exists then
- #don't push and exit with 0
- #else
- git push https://${GH_TOKEN}@github.com/${TRAVIS_REPO_SLUG} --tags`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply check if `git tag` succeeds locally before trying to push it (the `if` command suppresses the error return code):

```
...
export GIT_TAG=v1.0.$TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER
git fetch --tags
msg="Tag Generated from TravisCI for build $TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER"
if git tag $GIT_TAG -a -m "$msg" 2>/dev/null; then
    git push https://${GH_TOKEN}@github.com/${TRAVIS_REPO_SLUG} --tags
else
    echo Tag already exists!
fi
```

(Tag after the build ends, not before; this way you can skip the failures and tag only actual builds)

On a side note, I'd be worried if the build tag already exists, it means you won't have a reliable way to reproduce the current build in the future.

Comment: Thank you so much, this works like an absolute treat. What I did instead now is convert all my single lines in before_deploy: into a bash script called deploy.sh and now only have one line in before_deploy: which reads `travis/deploy.sh' this code of yours perfectly detects the tag, pushes once only and skips pushing on the rest of the build tests :) i owe you a six pack for that one.

Comment: I've got the tag pushing problem sorted but now stuck with making my script write to a simple .txt file and add it into the commit. Should I start a new question on this and post my code or add to this question? @sir-athos

Comment: Please start a new question for it. Adding sub-questions, especially when you've already accepted an answer, may lead to long waits for any solutions.

Comment: Thanks have done so at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42253765/getting-travisci-to-commit-and-push-a-modified-file-with-tags-releases

Comment: I've solved this riddle completely and posted my solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42253765/getting-travisci-to-commit-and-push-a-modified-file-with-tags-releases/42299765#42299765

Comment: @MitchellK I'm happy to hear you figured it out. Thanks for sharing the solution!

Comment: Added my acknowledgment to @Sir-Athos on my repo - https://github.com/mitchellkrogza/nginx-ultimate-bad-bot-blocker